# Activate / Deactivate Custom Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I have 4 fragments "in" a drawer.

```
MainActivity.java (extends FragmentActicity: contains DrawerLayout)
FragmentCreate.java (extends Fragment)
MyStuffFragment.java (extends Fragment)
ActivateFragment.java (extends Fragment)
LoginFragment.java (extends Fragment)
```

Then my custom broadcast receiver receiver:

```
MyReceiver.java (extends BroadcastReceiver)
```

I'm trying to activate/deactivate (in response to a activate and a deactivate button) the receiver: I register it statically in the manifest with the following code:

```
    <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and I make it start (in `ActivateFragment`) with:

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

or make it stop with `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED`.

The problem is: I don't know how to filter the action I want the receiver to be waiting for.
I get notified for both wifi or bluetooth changes, but I only want to get one of them, the one the user selected in `ActivateFragment`.
How can I dinamically change the action the receiver should be waiting for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //create static flag  isBluetooth=true;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       this.context = context;
         if(intent==null)
            return;
       String action = intent.getAction();
       if(action.equals("your_action"){
         isBluetooth = false;
         //do somthing
       }
       else{
         if(isBluetooth){
           // do somthing
           return;
         }
         /*do your normal stuff here*/
       }
    }

//above case is allowing you to use only one action i.e mutually exclusive.if you dont want this simply remove boolean  flag
```

Comment: I don't get the meaning of isBluetooth; when you say "your_action" you mean some particular event like "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGE"?